# google cloud voice in C#, having trouble with nuget dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, nuget

I have ran into a very confusing issue with trying to get google cloud voice recognition going on C#. In the past I had this running, but it seems like now I revisit making a console app for it in .net framework 4.6.1 I am running into a dependency issue.

here is the code:

```
public class googleVoiceRecognition
{
    public static SpeechRecognitionAlternative[] SyncRecognize(string filepath)
    {
        try
        {
            var speech = SpeechClient.Create();
            var response = speech.Recognize(new RecognitionConfig
            {
                Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                LanguageCode = "en-US"
            }, RecognitionAudio.FromFile(filepath));


            foreach (var result in response.Results)
                foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
                {
                    var newAlternatives = result.Alternatives;

                    try
                    {
                        var _orderNewAlternatives = (from alt in newAlternatives
                                                     select alt).OrderByDescending(c => c.Confidence);

                        var args = new List<string>();
                        foreach (var _alternative in _orderNewAlternatives)
                        {
                            args.Add(_alternative.Transcript);
                        }
                        if (args.Count > 0)
                            File.WriteAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\heard.txt", args.ToArray());
                        return _orderNewAlternatives.ToArray();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        SpeechRecognitionAlternative[] sys = { alternative };
                        return sys;
                    }

                    //return alternative.Transcript;
                }
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception i)
        {

            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I get this once the code hits the "SpeechClient.create()" line:

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"}
```

Now here is where it gets really messy, I can't downgrade to version 4.1.0 since google.Apis.Gax needs something higher than version 4.1.0. I tried downgrading Gax but then Gax.Grpc needs a certain version of Gax also. I am lost in what to do and I tried deleting all dependencies and it prevented me from doing do, and updating everything doesn't work either!

Other then that the code works just fine, since it is older code.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your whole project (.csproj, .packages, all files) to github or somewhere else I can inspect them?  I tried creating a Framework 4.6 app and calling the speech API and it worked: https://github.com/SurferJeffAtGoogle/csharp-docs-samples/tree/speech-overflow/speech/api/QuickStartF46

Comment: So basically I played around for a while and figured it was a compatibility issue with another google cloud nuget dependency. I kinda built a shortcut and built a secondary project to manage that part. I believe it is only with the speech, because the vision and translation together are fine, except when I add in the speech.

Comment: @ParkerBidigare: If you could update your question with a minimal example (which would presumably include the incompatible package in the project file, and a small console app that just made a request) that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Try refreshing your dependencies on Google packages with these commands inside the Nuget Package Manager Console:

```
PM> get-package -ProjectName <your-project-name> | Where {$_.Id -match "Google.*|Grpc.*" } | Uninstall-Package -Force
PM> Install-Package Google.Cloud.Speech.V1
```